# Changing my desktop enviroment to Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, lightdm

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer and now I want to change my desktop environment to Gnome 3. I have seen many methods to install Gnome 3 but now I am confused which method should I follow.
Please tell me if I can install Gnome 3 with just these commands without any other commands like adding repositories etc.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

&

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: @kos can you tell me if i install gnome 3 DE will my already installed applications in Unity will stay or not

Comment: If one of these answers solved your problem, just click the little grey **☑** under the number now turning it into beautiful green. This means "[yes, this answer is correct](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)"! **;-)** If there are multiple answers that solve your problem please pick the best one.

Answer (score 1):

Using Wily's (15.10) repositories, running the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

installs GNOME Shell 3.16.4.

I'm not certain if it's the same on 14.04, however. Give it a try. To find out the version of gnome-shell you're running, you can do the following:

```
gnome-shell --version
```

Comment: @ParanoidPanda The question wasn't whether or not it was a good idea. The question was how to do it. You downvoted me for nothing. Edit: I use gnome-shell and everything works fine for me. It's just a matter is preference.

Comment: I am sorry, I slightly misread the question, I have retracted my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Most convenient way is actually installing prepared [Ubuntu Gnome](http://ubuntugnome.org/) distribution.

Answer (score 0):

As the internal workings of Ubuntu are very much intertwined with Unity, it is quite hard to separate them and install the GNOME DE, so it is better to just do a fresh install of Ubuntu GNOME. Just running the commands you provided is likely just to cause problems especially if you try to then remove Unity to fully replace it.

To create a LiveUSB/LiveCD/LiveDVD follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) in order to then boot from it and [install it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop), and get the [latest Ubuntu GNOME ISOs here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/GetUbuntuGNOME) (you will find links at the bottom of the page to the latest ISO downloads).